# geoJson not validated

Tags: javascript, json, geojson

I have the following geoJson polygons:

```
{"type": "Feature","geometry":{"type":"MultiPolygon", "coordinates":[[[[103.76772700000001,1.47063],[103.76772700000001,1.4795775862068967],[103.758794,1.4795775862068967],[103.758794,1.47063],[103.76772700000001,1.47063]]]]},"properties": {"number":"01"}},

{"type": "Feature","geometry":{"type":"MultiPolygon", "coordinates":[[[[104.00891800000001,1.47063],[104.00891800000001,1.4795775862068967],[103.99998500000001,1.4795775862068967],[103.99998500000001,1.47063],[104.00891800000001,1.47063]]]]},"properties": {"number":"03"}}
```

But when I validate this in [geojson validator](http://geojsonlint.com/) it throws an EOF error. But when I try each separately it validates as a eligible geoJSON. So I tried with this too.

```
"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[

 {"type": "Feature","geometry":{"type":"MultiPolygon", "coordinates":[[[[103.76772700000001,1.47063],[103.76772700000001,1.4795775862068967],[103.758794,1.4795775862068967],[103.758794,1.47063],[103.76772700000001,1.47063]]]]},"properties": {"number":"01"}},

 {"type": "Feature","geometry":{"type":"MultiPolygon", "coordinates":[[[[104.00891800000001,1.47063],[104.00891800000001,1.4795775862068967],[103.99998500000001,1.4795775862068967],[103.99998500000001,1.47063],[104.00891800000001,1.47063]]]]},"properties": {"number":"03"}}

]
```

But still throwing an EOF error. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: its working in [ http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/ ]

Comment: It is not validating as a geoJSON but qualifies as a JSON.I could not understand

Comment: try to make the json as [  http://geojsonlint.com/#sample-geojson-content ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be an JSON object. You are missing the `{` and `}`.

```
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [

        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "MultiPolygon",
                "coordinates": [
                    [
                        [
                            [103.76772700000001, 1.47063],
                            [103.76772700000001, 1.4795775862068967],
                            [103.758794, 1.4795775862068967],
                            [103.758794, 1.47063],
                            [103.76772700000001, 1.47063]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            },
            "properties": {
                "number": "01"
            }
        },

        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "MultiPolygon",
                "coordinates": [
                    [
                        [
                            [104.00891800000001, 1.47063],
                            [104.00891800000001, 1.4795775862068967],
                            [103.99998500000001, 1.4795775862068967],
                            [103.99998500000001, 1.47063],
                            [104.00891800000001, 1.47063]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            },
            "properties": {
                "number": "03"
            }
        }

    ]
}
```

Comment: Exactly Thanks a lot